# GWT module: how to use the EntryPoint only in the test folder?

Tags: gwt, architecture

is it possible to include an `EntryPoint` inside the GWT project's `test` folder?

if so, how to refer this `EntryPoint` in the `[module-name].gwt.xml` file?

**my purpose:**

to build a JavaScript library wrapper as a *single GWT module* which separates the emulation environment (the `EntryPoint` class and its containers, panels etc.) into the `test` folder, while leaving the `src` folder clean from `EntryPoint` classes or containers and panels used for emulation.

that way, i can pack only the `src` folder into a jar, to be used as a clean GWT module.

currently i am building separate projects for the module and for the emulation - the emulation project reference and inherits the module, and the module is strictly clean (holds the public JS sources, but no `EntryPoint` or `HTML` / `CSS` files).

**note:**

already tried to add the test folder to the classpath or include it as a source in the `[module-name].gwt.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test folder usually execute java code and the gwt compiler doesn't compile code from there.  What it sounds like you may need is to put your wrapper gwt in a standalone module that doesn't have an entry point.  Then you need  module with an entry point just to bootstrap  the library module you have created to test the wrappers in the browsers.  It will be easiest if you create the test/bootstrap module as the project, then create a separate module for the wrapper stuff.  Be sure to include an  for the wrapper module in the project module so it can link in the wrapper code.

Comment: **this is exactly what i'm doing at the moment** (see above), was hoping for a way to embed those two together.

Comment: well, turns out this is the most appropriate solution for this case, so no changes required, and this answer is accepted.